# hide elements depending on the ui.router state nothing work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<section class="navbar" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl" ng-hide="$state.current.name === '/events'">
    <div class="navbar__container">
    </div>
</section>
```

I have this navbar and I want make it not show if I'm in the /events page.  Everything is set, but nothing happens.

```
$stateProvider.state('/events', {
 url: '/events',
 templateUrl: '/admin/event/event.tmpl.html',
 controller: 'EventCtrl'
});
```

What is the problem here? I can't figure out way is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ng-hide` doesn't work because your view doesn't know anything about `$state`.

To use `$state` in a view you need to assign it to scope variable in your controller.

```
$scope.$state = $state; // of course you need to inject it in your controller
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isState` filter with either `ng-show` or `ng-hide`.

`ng-show="('a.b.1' | isState) || ('a.b.2' | isState)"`